# Firebase: How to send notifications periodically from Firebase to android app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have an android app that uses Firebase real time database. I want to push notifications periodically or based on a timer to the android app. Are there any cloud functions supporting this feature?

Comment: A new concept of Firebase functions . May help you

Comment: Sure thing. You'll have to combine periodically triggering a Cloud Function from [this sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron) with sending FCM messages from [this sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications).