# Is it possible to push a notification periodicly or at a specific date? | Web Push

Tags: javascript, php, service-worker, web-push

I need to show a push notification once a week, even when the user is not on the page. I know it is possible to use service workers to push a notification based on a "feed", but I don't know if it is possible to push a notification at a specific date.

If it is possible, how could it be done with PHP (, if needed, and JavaScript, of course)?

Comment: It could be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php

Comment: No, I'm using service workers and I don't know how to work with Web Sockets.

Comment: And even if I did, it probably wouldn't be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're okay with using Firebase, one approach is to follow the [general advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44002849/firebase-how-to-send-notifications-periodically-from-firebase-to-android-app#comment75034397_44002849) that came up in another question, and customize it for the web:

- Use [Firebase Cloud Messaging's JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client) to implement your service worker's push message handler in your web clients.
- "Fake" a cron job by `POST`ing to a Firebase cloud function, following the example in [this sample app](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron). If you already have a PHP server running, that could be used to periodically trigger the Firebase cloud function. Alternatively, you could skip the Firebase cloud functions part entirely, and use your PHP server to [trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/first-message#send_a_notification_message) the push message directly.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not really a fan of using libraries. I'm gonna take a look at it and wait for more answers.